# getting error in DateTimeField is not defined in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting error on `DateTimeField` is not defined.I am trying to make date picker in react + bootstrap.

I take help from these URLs:

- http://dev.quri.com/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker/
- https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

---

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/18941xp52l

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            date: "1990-06-05",
            format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
            inputFormat: "DD/MM/YYYY",
            mode: "date"
        };
    }

    handleChange = newDate => {
        console.log("newDate", newDate);
        return this.setState({ date: newDate });
    };

    render() {
        const { date, format, mode, inputFormat } = this.state;
        return (
            <DateTimeField
                dateTime={date}
                format={format}
                viewMode={mode}
                inputFormat={inputFormat}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        );
    }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Did you import `DateTimeField` correctly? Do you have the package installed? Please add the full code with which you are trying (so including the importing statements)

Comment: wait I will update my question'

Answer (score 0):

You missed to import DateTimeField

```
import DateTimeField from "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker";
```